# Rails: scope из модели в self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

Я получаю фильтр фильмов путем присваивания @movies нового значения, но я хотел бы чтобы возвращало в self и кусок кода 
`@movies = @movies.filter_ratings(params[:ratings])` стал красивым:
`@movies.filter_ratings(params[:ratings])`

Рою гугл 2 день, помогите **пожалуйста**!

#### Мой контроллер:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @movies = Movie.sort_by(params[:sort_by])
    @movies = @movies.filter_ratings(params[:ratings]) unless (params[:ratings]).nil?
  end
end
```

#### Моя модель:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  # сортируем по требуемому полю
  scope :sort_by, ->(sorting) { all.order(sorting) }
  # выводим список рейтингов
  scope :all_ratings, -> { all.map{|movie| movie.rating }.uniq }
  # получаем фильмы согласно фильтру пользователя
  scope :filter_ratings, ->(filters) { where(:rating => filters.each_key.to_a) }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ActiveRecord нет методов (публичных как минимум), меняющих уже созданный `Relation`.

**Так задумано (см. комментарии к [этому коммиту в Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8c2c60511beaad05a218e73c4918ab89fb1804f0)).** API построителя запросов задуман, как иммутабельный, чтобы он был более предсказуемым, не вызывал неожиданного поведения где-то, где это не указано явно.

Но я не вижу ни единой причины, по которой `unless (params[:ratings]).nil?` нельзя проверять в самом скоупе, возвращая `self`, если изменения не требуются:

```
scope :filter_ratings, ->(filters) {
  if filters.nil?
    self
  else
    where(:rating => filters.each_key.to_a)
  end
}
```

Тогда сделать описанный вами запрос можно с помощью более длинной цепочки:

```
@movies = Movie.sort_by(params[:sort_by]).filter_ratings(params[:ratings])
```

Переносы/отступы по вкусу.

Comment: +1 тебе в карму! Долго бы я искал... и +1 в карму за подсказку, что в контроллер перенести проверку.

Comment: @AlkP в смысле-е... в модель :)

Comment: @AlkP не принципиально. Я использую первую, как более явную.

Comment: бррр... конечно же модель!.... оговорился, редактировал вопрос и в итоге ты отвечает, на то что другие не видят.  :) вопрос возник, т.к. читаю лучшие практики и везде большим и жирным (иногда с курсивом), что требуется писать как можно меньший код, но при этом таким же жирным и курсивом, что код должен быть "легким" и легко и читаемым и потому не всегда ясно, где кончается 1 правило и начинается 2... еще +1 тебе в карму, Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Отбирайте данные через query-обжект:

`app/controllers/movies_controller.rb`:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @movies = MoviesQuery.new(movies_query_params, Movie.all)
  end

  private

  def movies_query_params
    params.permit(:ratings, :sort_by)
  end
end
```

`app/queries/movies_query.rb`:

```
class MoviesQuery < ApplicationQuery
  action :filter_by_ratings,
         :sort_by_attribute

  def filter_by_ratings
    return unless query_params[:ratings].present?
    where(rating: query_params[:ratings].each_key.to_a)
  end

  def sort_by_attribute
    return unless query_params[:sort_by].in?(%w(created_at title rating))
    order(query_params[:sort_by])
  end
end
```

`app/queries/application_query.rb` - этот файл не меняется, можете копировать его из проекта в проект, и наследовать от него уже проектные query-обжекты:

```
class ApplicationQuery < SimpleDelegator
  attr_accessor :query_params

  def initialize(query_params, relation)
    @query_params = query_params
    self.relation = relation
    apply_actions
  end

  class_attribute :actions

  class << self
    def action(*args, &block)
      if block_given?
        actions << block
      elsif args.first.is_a?(Array)
        actions.push(*args.first)
      else
        actions.push(*args)
      end
    end

    def remove_action(action)
      actions.delete(action)
    end

    def actions
      @actions ||= []
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :relation

  def relation=(value)
    @relation = value
    __setobj__(@relation)
  end

  def apply_actions
    self.actions.each do |action|
      self.relation = evaluate_action(action) || relation
    end
  end

  def evaluate_action(action)
    if action.is_a?(Proc)
      instance_eval(&action)
    else
      send(action.to_sym)
    end
  end
end
```

`config/application.rb` - чтобы рельса увидела руби-файлы в папке `queries` - добавьте ее в `autoload_paths`:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(
      #{config.root}/app/queries
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: @AlkP,  почему 1я строка должна оставаться неизменной? Вся ваша конструкция в контроллере станет такой: `@movies = MoviesQuery.new(movies_query_params, Movie.all)`